# how to reduce spacing in the bitmap (render the text)

Tags: android

i already code to print the text in the form of image. then the problem is,when i print.the spacing is too far from each line. i dont know how. but in my code do not have "\n" .  i dont why it become like that. whether my drawtext or my drawbackground

```
public void drawText(String text, int textSize) { 

    TextPaint textPaint = new TextPaint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG | Paint.LINEAR_TEXT_FLAG); //(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG | Paint.LINEAR_TEXT_FLAG)
    textPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    textPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    textPaint.setTextSize(textSize);

    try
    {
        Typeface tf =Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/andalemono.ttf");
        textPaint.setTypeface(tf);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.d("your tag", "typeface error: ", e);
    }

    StaticLayout mTextLayout = new StaticLayout(text, textPaint, 370, Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 1.0f, 0.0f, false);

   //draw background
    Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG | Paint.LINEAR_TEXT_FLAG);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    float baseline = (int) (-paint.ascent() + 0.5f); 
    int height = (int) ((baseline + paint.descent()+ 0.5f + (textSize/2))); 
    Bitmap image = Bitmap.createBitmap(370, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(image);
    c.drawText(text,0, baseline, paint);
    c.drawPaint(paint);


    // Draw text
    c.save();
    c.translate(0,0);
    mTextLayout.draw(c);
    c.restore();
    printBitmap(image);
}
```

myfunction printBitmap()

```
public void printBitmap(Bitmap bmp)
{
    if (!myPrinter.printImage(bmp))
        return;

}
```

Comment: see the meanings of "1.0f, 0.0f" in StaticLayout constructor

Comment: i just found that code while im trying to render my text into bitmap. i dont know why im using  "1.0f,0.0f" i just know that is float. in constructor, it stand to  "float spacingmult, float spacingadd"

Comment: if you don't know why you are using those then change them and see the results

Comment: if i change it into 0,0 it will print nothing. the paper is blank. but when i try to use "1,0" or "1.0f,0.0f" or "1,5" it really do print. but the spacing is too far.

Comment: **spacingMult** - `factor by which to scale the font size to get the default line spacing` and **spacingAdd** - `amount to add to the default line spacing`

Comment: ouwh, so what suppose to do..

Comment: what suppose to do? try, experiment, not wait for other to give you a fish when you got a fishing rod

Comment: i am new in android.  actually i already try "1,0" , "1.0f,0.0f" , "1,5" , "5,0" , "100,0" , "-5,0" but it wont change the spacing. i already try the "height" in my code. if i put  int height = (int) ((baseline + paint.descent()+ 0.5f + (textSize/2)-10));  it really do reduce my spacing but when i print aphabet "p" it print "p" just like "D" with no tail..

Comment: the spacing is defined as: default_spacing * spacingMult + spacingAdd

Comment: and use the simple test code to try, for example: http://pastebin.com/v7YunF16

Comment: i already try by changing the value of spacingMult and spacingAdd. but still wont change

Comment: i have tried change the value of spacing mul and spacing add. even i put spacMul = 0 spacAdd=0 it still print. but empty. and also produce the same size of spacing.  i also tried 0 , 1.. still the same. i think it something else or maybe default spacing. i dont know..

Comment: again: the spacing is defined as: default_spacing * spacingMult + spacingAdd, this is a simple math

Comment: yeah, actually you right about the spacMult and spacAdd. but when i do that into my code it still cannot be change. so now i found out why it cannot be change. it related with another class activity. so after i adjust the class, i know how to use spacMult and spacAdd. thanks for your hint.  :)